# python str.replace does not work with '\'

Tags: python, string, split

In column `df['2']` I have a path with a filename:

```
C:\file1.txt
```

With code below I wanted to split off the filename:

df['2'].str.split('', n = 2, expand = True)

I get this error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-136-fe70d6bdb12c>", line 1
    df['2'].str.split('\', n = 2, expand = True)
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

What am I doing wrong? It works for every other string I put in there.

Comment: you need to escape the '\' with '\\' as: `df['2'].str.split('\\', n = 2, expand = True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of
`df['2'].str.split('\', n = 2, expand = True)`
try
`df['2'].str.split(chr(92), n = 2, expand = True)`

Answer (score 0):

you are escaping the ' char with \ so the string literal is invalid and the interpreter finds a Syntax Error

I would recommend to use [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) for this kind of operations on path names, it is easy and and as a bonus it will work on every OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python 3.4 or newer, the built in `pathlib` library works really well with paths. It eliminates most of the pain from / and . To get your implementation to work Krishnas suggestion in the comments should do the trick.

Here is anyway how to do this with pathlib:

```
from pathlib import Path

filename = Path(df['2'].str).stem
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html